# What is the correct way to use a .xbm image in source code?

Tags: c++, bitmap, x11, pixmap

I noticed that X bitmap (.xbm) image files double as valid C code, I assume so you can easily embed them in programs. It `#define`s constants for the width and height of the image, and includes the image data as a `char` array. That is, if you open the image as a text file, you'll see something like this:

```c
#define radio_on_width 13
#define radio_on_height 13
static char radio_on_bits[] = {
 0xe0,0x00,0x18,0x03,0x04,0x04,0xe2,0x08,0xf2,0x09,0xf9,0x13,0xf9,0x13,0xf9,
 0x13,0xf2,0x09,0xe2,0x08,0x04,0x04,0x18,0x03,0xe0,0x00};
```

What is considered best practice for taking advantage of this in a project containing multiple source files? Right now, I have a header file which contains the following:

```c
#ifndef BITMAPS_H
#define BITMAPS_H

//...

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wnarrowing"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"

// Radio buttons
#include "bitmaps/radio_off.xbm"
#include "bitmaps/radio_off_pressed.xbm"
#include "bitmaps/radio_on.xbm"
#include "bitmaps/radio_on_pressed.xbm"

#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

// ...

#endif // BITMAPS_H
```

And then I `#include` that when I need to use the bitmaps. I know that normally header files should only include declarations, not definitions, but the `static` declaration means that isn't a problem in this case, right? I have the header file `#include`d in multiple source files, and it works for me so far, but it seems like something that might be considered bad practice, as it puts a separate copy of the array in every object file whose source file includes my header file. This shouldn't be an issue for small images like I'm using, but for larger images that are `#include`d many times I could see it wasting space if the linker isn't smart enough to consolidate the arrays to a single copy. (Though with GCC at least, the `-fmerge-all-constants` option appears to do the job.)

Is there some reason why what I'm doing is a bad idea, or is it an accepted practice?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages and may have different considerations. Please tag only one of the languages.

Comment: @kaylum This specific project is C++, so I'll remove the C tag. That said, I'm also interested to know if there's any C-specific concerns. And if something is a bad idea in C++, I'd also be interested in knowing (for future reference) whether the concern is specific to C++ or it applies to C as well.

Comment: I would `#include` all `.xbm` files in one single `.cc` or `.c` file that contains globlal pointers at the end of the `#includes`: `const char *radio_on_xbm = radio_on_bits;` or `const char * Bitmaps::radio_on = radio_on_bits;` However, this is my personal preference. Note that the arrays are not `const`. For `-fmerge-all-constants`, you would need something like `#define static static const`.